# to_string not recognized as a member of string OSX Mavericks using g++

Tags: string, append

I'm trying to use `to_string` to append an integer value to a string like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int number = 1;
    string p = "Player";

    p += to_string(number);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to compile it I get an error stating `to_string was not declared in this scope`, so I removed the `using namespace std;` and replaced `to_string` with `std::to_string`, but now I get a new error saying that `to_string` is not a member of `std`.

This problem only occurs when I compile from the command line but it works perfectly in XCode.

Any ideas on why this is? (I need to be able to compile it from the command line for a hw assignment)

Comment: `std::to_string` is part of C++11.

Comment: Yes this method is part of C++11. You can try your program online from the following link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: thanks @tmp it works on that site!

Answer (score 1):

`to_string` is a feature of C++11, did you use the flag *--std=c++11*?

Comment: thanks for the advice! I just tried it however i got an error message saying it was an unrecognized command line option

Comment: @Matt, probably you are running on older gcc version. You can try online gcc4.8 compiler which supports c++11.                  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/